# Не находит тег p:focus jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть **div** с **id="editor"**. У него задано **contenteditable**. Дальше, в нем лежит 3 тега **p**. находясь в каком то из них (стоит курсор) я хочу получить индекс этого **p**. Для этого я делаю

```
$("#editor p:focus").index();
```

И получаю -1, то есть не находит. Вопрос: почему?

Уточнение: если сделать так

```
console.log($(":focus").html());
```

Выводит содержимое дива с id #editor. Выходит, что p не может получить фокус?

Comment: вы бы этот `contenteditable` перенесли в каждый `p` а не у дива, тогда бы работало все. Редактируются то там у вас сразу все три  `p`, а не какой то один из  них. Будете редактировать по  одному, и получите свой фокус

Comment: вопрос - каким образом курсор должен попасть в p,  и какое содержимое у p ?

Comment: @teran, я уже пробовал для каждого p прописать, но результата это не дало. или еще надо тогда у родителя убрать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

есди я правильно понял проблему, то вам необходимо получить индекс р, в котором находится курсор.
можете посмотреть следующее решение:

```js
 let div = document.querySelector('div');
let arrP = Array.from(div.querySelectorAll('p'));
div.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  let pStart = range.startContainer.nodeType === 3
    ? range.startContainer.parentNode.closest('p')
    : range.startContainer.closest('p')
  let pEnd = range.endContainer.nodeType === 3
    ? range.endContainer.parentNode.closest('p')
    : range.endContainer.closest('p')
console.log(arrP.indexOf(pStart),arrP.indexOf(pEnd))
  
})
```

```html
<div contenteditable = "true">
  <p>test0</p>
  <p>test1</p>
  <p>test2</p>
 </div>
```

если нужны пояснения, то спрашивайте.
да, и фокус передается не р  а contenteditable элементу

Comment: спасибо большое, то что надо

Comment: можете еще подсказать, как использовать ваш код, если надо узнать границы выделения? то есть, если я выбрал текст двоих p, то можно было узнать их индексы? пробую сам - что то не выходит изменить

Comment: сча поменяю код